# How to determine Controller for given url (spring)

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Using spring DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping how can I lookup the Controller that would ultimately handle a given url.

I currently have this, but feels like there ought to be a cleaner way than iterating over 100s of request mappings:

```
public static Object getControllerForAction(String actionURL) {
    ApplicationContext context = getApplicationContext();
    AnnotationHandlerMapping mapping = (AnnotationHandlerMapping) context.getBean("annotationMapper");
    PathMatcher pathMatcher = mapping.getPathMatcher();
    for (Object key: mapping.getHandlerMap().keySet()) {
        if (pathMatcher.match((String) key, actionURL)){
            return mapping.getHandlerMap().get(key);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would need to find this out.. ?

Comment: I have a jsp tag that takes in a url string, and I want to either show or hide the tag result based on some custom annotations in the mapped controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the purposes of this question, all of the interesting methods in `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and its superclasses are protected, and so not visible to external code. However, it would be trivial to write a custom subclass of `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` which overrides these methods and makes them `public`.

Since you need to be able to supply a path rather than a request object, I would suggest `lookupHandler` of `AbstractUrlHandlerMapping` would be a good candidate for this. It still needs you to supply it with a request object as well as the path, but that request object is only used to pass to the validateHandler() method, which does nothing, so you could probably supply a null there.

Comment: No need for subclasses. As I said in my answer, getHandler() is public since it's declared on HandlerMapping interface. It does return `HandlerExecutionChain` but it's easy to unwrap.

Comment: As the OP pointed out, getHandler() is no use for his needs. I've modified my answer to accomodate.

Comment: To be fair, he pointed that out after both our answers :-) At any rate, validateHandler() is overriden in `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and passing request as null is NOT an option because it's very much used there.

Comment: skaffman, thank you, your answer does seem to be working with passing null. I'll comment if I run into problems with validateHandler.

Comment: Ever get the feeling that the Spring guys just didn't want us to do this? :) It looks like null request won't cut it here, and so you could try passing in a MockHttpServletRequest instead, and populate that mock with the things required by validateHandler(). Awkward, but do-able.

Answer (score 2):

All mappers implement `HandlerMapping` interface which has a `getHandler()` method:

```
ApplicationContext context = getApplicationContext();
AnnotationHandlerMapping mapping = (AnnotationHandlerMapping) context.getBean("annotationMapper");
Object controller = mapping.getHandler().getHandler();
```

`HandlerMapping.getHandler()` returns `HandlerExecutionChain`, calling `getHandler()` on that would return you the actual handler which - for controller mapper - would be the controller you're looking for.

Comment: The problem with HandlerMapping.getHandler(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) is that it takes in a request and I need to handle a situation before the request for the url is created (in a jsp tag).

Comment: Fair enough, although you didn't say that in your question. In that case I would either go with the way you have it now or take a look at **skaffman**'s suggestion below but be aware of possible issues with NULL request object

Answer (score 2):

Above doesn't work in Spring 3.1. You can do the following instead.

```
Map<String, AbstractHandlerMethodMapping> map = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(servletContext).getBeansOfType(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.class);
Iterator<AbstractHandlerMethodMapping> iter = map.values().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    AbstractHandlerMethodMapping ahmb = iter.next();
    Iterator<Object> urls = ahmb.getHandlerMethods().keySet().iterator();
    while (urls.hasNext()) {
        Object url = urls.next();
        logger.error("URL mapped: " + url);
    }           
}
```